# Refactoring ZF Controller file?

Tags: php, zend-framework, refactoring

I have a controller that is (IMO) too long (over 1200 lines). 
The main problem is that I have a lot of actions in it.
I can group this actions in 3 groups:

1. calendar related actions
2. events related actions (let's call events a "submodule" of calendar)
3. providers related actions (also a "submodule" of the calendar)

What would be the best way to reorganize the code.
Could I, somehow, split it in sub-classes? 
Or is there any ZF-specific way to achieve this goal without creating additional controllers for the calendar "submodules"?

Comment: [Phrases to avoid](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help4) include "Sir", "Thanks in advance", "ASAP" and even a bland "Help me" deimpresses people. Also I wonder if your problem is specific to Zend Framework because you ask that way.

Comment: I can't tell if it's specific to ZF or it applies to any framework because ZF it's the only framework I work with, and also I'm a novice with it. Regarding the "Thank you", I didn't know about that. Phrase removed.

Comment: So let's add some more info: Can it be that mainly your controllers actions (class methods) are growing large? Is it that you can not re-group into different controllers because all actions belong to each other? And is it likely that you have duplicate code within the actions? In Refactoring you normally can apply certain methods, however these always depend on the concrete code (which is not part of your question and it's probably also not useful to share it here (check the code-review site if it still exists)). See http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring

Comment: @ hakra, thanks for the link! Also, I added additional info to make my question more clear.

Comment: Are you aware that you can create modules in Zend Framework (1) application?

Comment: Yes. And the CalendarController is already in the "frontend" module. Can I have a module under another module?

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible with Zend Framework 1, but I'm not that fluent with it. The docs should be able to tell you that. Also if you look into the controller actions, is there duplicate code?

Comment: How many actions are there in your controller and what's the average method length? I'm asking because usually a too large controller is a sign that too much business logic resides in the controller. Always keep the "Fat Model Skinny Controller" paradigm in mind.

Comment: 37 actions and 30 lines is the average method length. So the question is, how could I make it "thin"? Using sub-modules - there is no clear specifications about submodules in ZF1? Or... how?

Comment: Well it's one approach to keep controllers thin and the model fat, however a) in Zend Framework 1 is not much Model by default and b) when the controllers are already fat, it's a bit late I'd say. -- you can technically introduce any level of submodules by controlling the loading of the controllers via the routing. I'd say this page in the manual is a good start: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.modular.html - You might use this already, so you could create *your* version of that (perhaps in a plugin) that support sub-modules in routing and view loading.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a best way.

If you think your class is to big, you have to split the class based on separations of concerns principle.

The Principle of Separation of Concerns states that system elements should have *exclusivity* and *singularity* of purpose. That is to say, no element should share in the responsibilities of another or encompass unrelated responsibilities.

Separation of concerns is achieved by the establishment of boundaries. A boundary is any logical or physical constraint which delineates a given set of responsibilities.

If your class does not violates the Separation of concerns principle, leave it as it is.